# open div on same page as bootstrap accordion with accordion heading

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to hide and show images in a div next to an bootstrap accordion. The javascript I'm using works, there is only one problem.

I want when the accordion is closed, hide the div with the images, this works if I click the same accordion heading. 
Unfortunately if the accordion is open and I click another heading the div with the images hides.

I know that it is probably better to use Jquery for this or I need to use an argument or condition for it in javascript, but I'm a cut and paste kinda guy and I couldn't find anything that I could use or easily modify.
This is the script:

```
function slideContent(id) {
if ($('#' + id).css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#' + id).slideDown('100', function () { });
}
else {
    $('#' + id).slideUp('100', function () { });
}
}
</script>
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/C7caU/21/.
Only the javascript doesn't work in the fiddle not showing the div with images on click. Why I don't know, it does work in the browser.
This fiddle works properly now thanks to Shukla Jay

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your javascript not working problem is solved. I don't understand your other problems from this. Check ans and feel free to ask if any problem is there.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify the wrap setting it defaults to "onLoad". This results with all JavaScript being wrapped in a function run after result has been loaded. All variables are local to this function thus unavailable in the global scope.

Change the wrapping setting to "no wrap" and it'll work:

Your bootstrap version file have some problem. I just changed it to this.

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">  </script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

`Updated Fiddle` [See Here](http://jsfiddle.net/C7caU/20/)

Comment: thanks for solving the javascript. What I want to do is when the heading of accordion is clicked that the containing div with the images is shown that works with this script.But if the accordion is open and I click another heading the images hide, I would like them to show. So that there are always images shown when the acordion is open. In the fiddle the headings open when you click on them, this is not what I intended, only 1 accordion content at the time should be shown.

Comment: I was working on it as well and put the 2.3.1. in as well, the only thing was that the divs with the images aren't next to the accordion.I would like to have something added to the javascript that when a accordion heading is clicked, the images show and if I click on another accordion heading the images are still shown and when the accordion is closed only the 2 images are visible next to the accordion. Thanks for your help so far, hope you can sort this one out too.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. what you want.

Comment: is there a possibility that I can have the div that hides, stay open when I click on another heading, because now with every click the javascript hides or shows the div no matter which heading I click. So click on heading div shows, click on another heading the shown div stays open, unless you click on the same heading .

Comment: I made a new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j2KSB/.Now it is showing the images next to the accordion.I had to expand the window where the result is showing. There must be some javascript addition to keep the the div(pics)open, when I click another accordion heading.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tag = '';
function slideContent(id) {
if(id == tag){
    if (($('#pics').css('display') == 'none') && (id == tag)) {
        $('#pics').slideDown('100');
        tag = id;
    }else {
        $('#pics').slideUp('100');
        tag = '';
    }
   }else{
    $('#pics').slideDown('100');
    tag = id;
}
}

</script>
```

Just replace # pics with your own.